# InnoSetup: Verify that .NET 2.0 is installed

Tags: inno-setup

I have a component that requires minimum .NET 2.0 to run, how can my Inno Setup installer verify there is atlast .Net 2.0 installded, and if not, install .Net 2.0 from slience

I have include 32bit and 64bit of .Net 2.0 in Setup folder

Can u help me please

Comment: check out this search [link](http://www.bing.com/search?q=inno+setup+checking+framework+version&qs=n&form=QBLH&pq=inno+setup+checking+framework+version&sc=0-20&sp=-1&sk=&ghc=1&cvid=35781f43d3d84fc2a41e93e6af745094)

Comment: I don't think it's a good idea to redistribute nor install framework which is 8 years old and which is part of Windows Vista up.

Comment: What i want is check if there is an .Net version install that laster than .Net 2.0 then skip .Net install. if no then install .Net 2.0